# Under 'Last Exec', using String Deduplication settings for the JVM, why are so many listed as 'deduplicated', when so few are described as 'new'

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

I realize that this may seem an obvious question, but given context, it appears a little less clear.  For example in the below printout of an execution of 'concurrent-string-deduplication', 2604 were inspected, only 2 were listed as known, but 1159 are listed as 'deduplicated'.  Also, if only 2 were 'known', why were 1784 'hashed'.  I haven't been able to find a clear description of all of the values printed using string deduplication, yet.  Can anyone explain what the 1159 deduplicated represents, if only 2 of the inspected were previously 'known'?

```
2019-08-23T01:36:58.133-0700: 133229.334: [GC concurrent-string-deduplication, 139.2K->76.0K(63.3K), avg 94.4%, 0.0011438 secs]
   [Last Exec: 0.0011438 secs, Idle: 764.1634320 secs, Blocked: 0/0.0000000 secs]
      [Inspected:            2604]
         [Skipped:              0(  0.0%)]
         [Hashed:            1784( 68.5%)]
         [Known:                2(  0.1%)]
         [New:               2602( 99.9%)    139.2K]
      [Deduplicated:         1159( 44.5%)     63.3K( 45.4%)]
         [Young:                0(  0.0%)      0.0B(  0.0%)]
         [Old:               1159(100.0%)     63.3K(100.0%)]
   [Total Exec: 2745/99.6585221 secs, Idle: 2745/133125.2026363 secs, Blocked: 69/0.1752133 secs]
      [Inspected:       127861879]
         [Skipped:              0(  0.0%)]
         [Hashed:       127470832( 99.7%)]
         [Known:            64119(  0.1%)]
         [New:          127797760( 99.9%)     20.8G]
      [Deduplicated:    121664152( 95.2%)     19.6G( 94.4%)]
         [Young:         90179638( 74.1%)     13.2G( 67.5%)]
         [Old:           31484514( 25.9%)   6518.5M( 32.5%)]
   [Table]
      [Memory Usage: 10.3M]
      [Size: 262144, Min: 1024, Max: 16777216]
      [Entries: 352870, Load: 134.6%, Cached: 8901, Added: 6190513, Removed: 5837643]
      [Resize Count: 22, Shrink Threshold: 174762(66.7%), Grow Threshold: 524288(200.0%)]
      [Rehash Count: 0, Rehash Threshold: 120, Hash Seed: 0x0]
      [Age Threshold: 3]
   [Queue]
      [Dropped: 0]
[GC concurrent-string-deduplication, deleted 0 entries, 0.0000003 secs]
```

Comment: “Hashed” means that their hash code has been calculated, which is a necessary prerequisite for looking up equal strings. So this applies to all strings, whose hash code hasn’t been calculated before by the application already (mind that the string class caches the hash code). I think, “Known” contains the already known strings which are also “Inspected” in this particular round, so it doesn’t (re)check all existing old strings in each cycle.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger.  If 2604 were inspected, and only 1784 were hashed, how is that there are 2602 reported as 'new'.  Why wouldn't more have been hashed, assuming that hashing equates 'unknown'?

Comment: As said, the `String` class caches the hash code. So when the application did already use the hash code, e.g. when storing the string into a `HashSet` or using it as a key of a `HashMap`, before the deduplication triggered (by default, a string has to survive three gc cycles before it kicks in), the hash code does not need to be calculated again.